# Why has a player's castle became nothing but ruin?

Tags: shadow-kings

I attacked a player a while back who was near me (so I could get my troops back) to complete the quest which required me to attack a city.

When I was looking around recently to see who was around me and their strength I noticed where a player was now a destroyed city, when I went to espionage or attack I get a message saying that nothing lives there and there is only ruin.

I am wondering what happened? Did I play a hand in that?

Answer (score 1):

Having had some people join my alliance and being able to see what they were last on, I have noticed a coloration to their Castles becoming to ruin and their last login time being >= 7 days.

Also, Force Fields seem to protect your castle from becoming ruins and I think the minimum is 7 days (as per alot of the potions and scrolls)